# How can I call the database details from SQL server in WordPress

Tags: sql-server, database, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with MySQL database. I want to call some database details from SQL server. But the SQL server is running in another server. Is it possible?

I just tried this:

```
global $wpdb;
$mydb = new wpdb(SQLserver_DB_USER, SQLserver_DB_PASSWORD, SQLserver_database_name, SQLserver_installed_pc_ip_adress);

$rows = $mydb->get_results("select * from table_name");
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Are you asking how to connect PHP to SQL Server, or how to use Wordpress on SQL Server here..?

Comment: @Larnu Actually I want to call some table details from SQL server in my WordPress site. Now i'm using the MySQL database for WordPress, I don't want to change that. I want to call some additional data from another server. I don't know that is possible or not.

eg: WordPress running in 192.168.8.1 and the SQL server is running in 192.168.8.2. I want to call the sql server database content from (192.168.8.2) to my WordPress site(192.168.8.1 ).

Comment: For example, a company directory SQL database on another server and I'd like to write a Wordpress code where I can connect to that separate server and query tables, etc. Nothing to do with the MySQL back-end of WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I just used this code,

```
$serverName = "external_server_ip_address(192.168.8.2)"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db_name", "UID"=>"user_name", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

> NOTE: Make sure your PHP have `pdo_sqlsrv` support. Otherwise
>   `sqlsrv_connect` will not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not working isn't very clear. What is not working?

*Are you not getting any data or connection at all?*
Try it with the actual host name as last parameter instead of the IP address.

*Are you getting results but it's from your main db?*
Try to flush the wp_cache before you make the call to the new db

```
wp_cache_flush()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21527572)

Comment: Answers don't have to be exhaustive or infallible, they just need to try to answer the question. It's perfectly fine to post an answer saying, for example, "I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but if it's X, you can solve it by doing Y. If that doesn't help, try Z and let me know what it says." Also, if further information does become available, you can edit your answer later to make it more precise. This is a good habit to get into even if you can comment!